# Firefox php file "The system cannot find the file specified."

Tags: php, firefox, iis

I have a very annoying problem with a website that I have uploaded to a hosting server. When I try to view php pages with Firefox in Windows from the server all it says in the browser is "The system cannot find the file specified.". It had been working for years before this and I have not changed anything on the server.

When I use the same link in Internet Explorer, it will load the page. I tried flushing the dns cache and clearing the Firefox cache but still have had no luck. I cleared the IE cache to make sure that IE was not storing it somehow as well and it still worked fine on IE.

I have tried googling that error message but it seems to usually be related to windows files missing etc. and I couldn't not find anything specifically to do with Firefox not loading a page.

What else can I do to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Try in other browsers, also try to access the url from other machines firefox browser.

Comment: Yes it happens on other machines with firefox too but IE works.

Comment: Can you post the URL so we can also test?

Comment: I can send you the URL but I don't want to make it public

Comment: this url is showing `The page cannot be found` in chrome and FF, even on Safari.

Comment: try labeleditor.php instead of test.php

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29885/discussion-between-asagohan-and-yogesh-suthar)

Comment: Its working in all 3 browsers. Showing `Alternate HTML content should be placed here. This content requires the Adobe Flash Player. Get Flash` in FF and Safari, because flash is not installed in them.

Comment: Inspect the request to see whether at least it tries to make a request and to what. And to get the actual status code.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming your .php file to .php5 is a work around proposed in the link below for Google Chrome.

[The system cannot find the file specified. - error in Chrome on PHP files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546851/the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-error-in-chrome-on-php-files)

Comment: Thanks, but I can't check if that is an option or not because magically it is all working again. I am pretty sure it was the hosting provider but I can't prove it and I was never able to convince them of the problem in the first place.