# The system cannot find the file specified. - error in Chrome on PHP files

Tags: php, google-chrome

I have a particularly frustrating problem. I have a hosted website which has a couple of simple PHP files. The files open up in Safari, and IE; but are giving me an error message on Chrome of "The system cannot find the file specified."

I've tried cleaning out the Chrome cache and browser history, uninstalled and reinstalled chrome and yet no luck. I called up my hosting service and they are saying that they can see it fine on their systems through Chrome.

Any ideas?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks,

Kris

Comment: Are you trying on another PC or laptop??....just for discard hardware

Comment: This sounds like an issue with Chrome itself.  That message is vaguely familiar to me from C or Java.  I'd try uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome altogether.

Comment: I'm getting this error on a notebook running Win7. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome - no luck

Comment: So far I've been able to replicate it on other Win7 machines running Chrome

Comment: I've found a workaround on this. When I change the file name from .php to .php5 it works fine on all browsers.

Comment: Was your hosting service domain.com? Because I had the exact same issue and I couldn't convince them it was a problem at their end either. Now all of a sudden it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround. By renaming the .php to .php5, it seems to work on all the browsers. I wonder whether some file binding has been messed up on the server side.

UPDATE - I found out that it was an issue with my hosting service. They fixed something on their end and things started working find. So if you have this issue, get your provider to fix it. I had a hell of a time convincing the support folks that this could even be a problem on their end. They kept asking me to flush my browser cache.